# Avoid restarting bot when creating server-global channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So basically i have this simple 'World Chat' script that lets people who have my bot and a channel called "world_chat" chat with each other in that channel, they can receive and send messages but the problem here is, every time they create a channel either with a command I gave or manually, they will be able to send messages and others can see it but they won't be able to see what others send till i reset the bot on heroku which I really don't want to do as when the bot gets in a lot of servers it'd be a lot of work.

```
#This is the script that let's people chat to each other
saki_chans=[]
async def get_saki_chans():
    for i in client.servers:
        for x in i.channels:
            if x.type == discord.ChannelType.text and x.name == 
'world_chat' and x.id not in saki_chans:
                saki_chans.append(x.id)
    print(saki_chans)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.server and message.channel.name == 'world_chat' and 
message.author.id != client.user.id:
        for i in saki_chans:
            if i == message.channel.id:
                pass
            else:
            
emb=discord.Embed(title='',description='{}'.format(message.content),colour 
= discord.Color.gold)
                emb.set_author(name= message.author.name)
                await client.send_message(discord.Object(id=i),embed=emb)
```

## And this is the script that creates the channel on a command

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def get_wchat(ctx):
    servr = ctx.message.server
    await client.create_channel(servr, 'world_chat', 
type=discord.ChannelType.text)
```

I expect when someone says '(prefix)create_wchat' it creates a channel called 'world_chat' but I don't have to restart the bot or script for the person to receive messages others send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `await get_saki_chans()` in your `get_wchat` command to update your global channels list every time one is created.

Currently you only call it once, on startup, so that's why you have to restart your bot.

However, instead of asking the user to invoke a specific command, I suggest you listen to [`on_channel_create`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_channel_create), `on_channel_delete` and `on_channel_update` events so simply creating a channel called `#world_chat`, or renaming an existing one to this name ; makes it a world_chat channel.

Similarly you would avoid keeping a channel no longer named `#world_chat` or deleted.

Comment: This only work s for the script but if a channel is created manually then it won't work.

Comment: @Unknown That's what the "However" part is

Comment: @Unknown Unsing events, you can check whenever a channel is created if its name is "world_chat" (will say 'wc' now) and if so add it to the list. ; whenever a channel is deleted, if its name is 'wc' remove it from the list ; and whenever a channel is updated, if its name becomes 'wc' add it to the list ; if its name was 'wc' and changed remove it from the list.

Comment: This handles every channels, and also handle when a channel isn't world_chat anymore.